# Python - pyodbc call stored procedure with parameter name

Tags: sql-server, django, python-2.7, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I need to call a `SqlServer stored procedure` from `python2.7` via `pyodbc` module with input parameter name.

I tried based on [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) by input parameter order:

```
cursor.execute('{CALL [SP_NAME](?,?)}',
              ('value', 'value'))
```

It works, but I need to pass `parameter name of stored procedure` because order of stored procedure input parameter always changes. So I need to pass them by name.

```
cursor.execute('{CALL [SP_NAME](@param1name,@param2name)}',
              ('value', 'value'))
```

However this doesn't work. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: What driver are you using, and are you on Linux or Windows? Sometimes, the TDS and driver version can affect stored procedures.

Comment: @FlipperPA Thanks for your attention. I'm using Windows 8. And about driver i didn't get it. what do you mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I tested this using the following stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[breakfast] 
    @person varchar(50) = 'nobody', 
    @food varchar(50) = 'tofu'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @person + ' likes to eat ' + @food
END
```

**The Bad News ("CALL")**

I found that

```python
sql = """\
{ CALL breakfast (@food=?, @person=?) }
"""
params = ('bacon','Gord')
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

gave inconsistent results.

With the `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` ODBC driver it ignored the parameter *names* and treated the parameters as positional, yielding ...

```
bacon likes to eat Gord
```

... and with the older `{SQL Server}` ODBC driver I just got the error

> DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

**The Good News ("EXEC")**

I found that

```python
sql = """\
EXEC breakfast @food=?, @person=?
"""
params = ('bacon','Gord')
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

gave me the following (correct) result using both ODBC drivers

```
Gord likes to eat bacon
```

Answer (score -3):

This syntax appears to work for me:

```
cursor.execute('{CALL [SP_NAME](@param1name=?, @param2name=?)}',
('value', 'value'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. see @GordThompson's answer :)