# Does pyodbc support any form of named parameters?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyodbc

I know sqlite3 has

```
data = {'test_col': 012345679}
sqlite3_conn.execute("""
    UPDATE test_db SET test_col = :test_col
    ;""", data)
```

and mysql-connector-python has

```
data = {'test_col': 012345679}
mysql_conn.execute("""
    UPDATE test_db SET test_col = %(test_col)s
    ;""", data)
```

but does pyodbc support any form of named parameters? I like being able to just pass a `dict` to the execute method. It is very convenient, and with some of my queries, such as `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it is needed.

Comment: The short answer is "No" (ref: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyodbc/zuXrEgk_14A)). In some cases a workaround is possible, e.g., with EXEC for stored procedures in T-SQL, as explained in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34179375/2144390).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't support named parameters, but bound parameters passed in the correct order are fairly straightforward:

```
x = "This"
y = 345

mssql_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE colx = ? AND coly = ?", x, y)
```

or

```
mssql_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE colx = ? AND coly = ?", (x, y))
```

More details and options here, such as passing `executemany` parameters:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

Good luck!

Comment: Those are qmark style placeholders. I am talking about named style placeholders, or named parameters: [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) --> `:colname`; [mysql-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) --> `%(colname)s`

Comment: I haven't been in the code in a while, but last I was, they were not supported. You can pass as `x, y` or `(x, y)`. With `executemany`, you can pass as `((x, y), (a, b))`. You can make a feature request here, it would be nice to have: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function to convert an `execute` method that only accepts positional parameters into a wrapper function that accepts named parameters. Use a regex pattern that grabs the name after a colon but ignores quoted strings and comments:

```
import re

def to_positional(func, _pattern=re.compile(r"'(?:''|[^'])*'|--.*|:(\w+)")):
    def execute(operation, namespace):
        def replacer(match):
            if name := match[1]:
                params.append(namespace[name])
                return '?'
            return match[0]
        params = []
        return func(_pattern.sub(replacer, operation), params)
    return execute
```

so that you can call the wrapped `execute` method with a query with named parameters:

```
sql = """\
UPDATE products
SET
    name=:name,
    price=:price,
    description=':description ''' || :description || ''''
WHERE id=:id; -- :comment
"""
data = {'id': 123, 'name': 'foo', 'price': 99.99, 'description': 'foo description'}
to_positional(mssql_cur.execute)(sql, data)
```

To more easily see the transformed query without involving a database you can make the helper function wrap `print` instead of `mssql_cur.execute`:

```
to_positional(print)(sql, data)
```

so it would output:

```
UPDATE products
SET
    name=?,
    price=?,
    description=':description ''' || ? || ''''
WHERE id=?; -- :comment
 ['foo', 99.99, 'foo description', 123]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/tXlAfP

Answer (score 0):

pyodbc itself does not support named parameters, but SQLAlchemy does, thereby making named parameters available to any database that has a SQLAlchemy dialect.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@my_mssql_dsn")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        sa.text("UPDATE test_db SET test_col = :param_a"),
        {"param_a": 123},
    )
```