# How to check if a specific string exists in a specific column, in a specific SQL DB table using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, pypyodbc

I am trying to create a Login Window (tkinter), and I am trying to get the inputs in a SQL DataBase Table.
[image]

I am getting an error at this code, I am also trying to see wether the inputs are already in the table or no:

```py
def check (username, password):
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = :username and password = :password", username=username, password=password)
```

This is the error:
[image]

This is how I am calling the function:

```py
def checkLogin():
    name = name_var.get()
    password = passw_var.get()
    connectiontosql.check(name, password)
```

Note: connectiontosql is another module, created by me.

I have little to no knowledge in SQL, google didn't help too much, sorry if it's dead easy.

Comment: I *think* `pyodbc` might be expecting parameter placeholders like `?` rather than `:username` at least looking at this example https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does pyodbc support any form of named parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748982/does-pyodbc-support-any-form-of-named-parameters)

Comment: note quite :D
https://imgur.com/a/pMV9xZC

Comment: Try: `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = ? and password = ?", [username, password])` using square brackets rather than round