# Python 3.6 pyodbc to SQL How to execute SP

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pycharm, pyodbc

I've created a Python script to execute an SP using my cursor with connection odbc. I've tried everything I found but I can not execute the desired procedure. My code below:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                           'SERVER=XXXXXX;'
                           'DATABASE=XXX;UID=XXXX;'
                           'PWD=XXX')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cmd_prod_executesp = 'EXECUTE DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate'
cursor.execute(cmd_prod_executesp)
conn.close()
```

I have tried:

```
cmd_prod_executesp = '{call DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate}'
cmd_prod_executesp = 'exec DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate'
cmd_prod_executesp = '{CALL DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate}'
```

I appreciate your help

thanks so much

Comment: does your sp take any parameters?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO not buddy is just a simple execute but it is driving me crazy!!

Comment: try putting the sql directly in the `execute()` like this `cursor.execute(" exec DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate")` also do you get any errro  messages?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO neither buddy :( gosh!!

Comment: Are you getting an error returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - pyodbc call stored procedure with parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964608/python-pyodbc-call-stored-procedure-with-parameter-name)

Comment: any error at all just a happy message 'Process finished with exit code 0' but when i go to my DB nothing was executed :(

Comment: What is your way of checking what got executed in your DB? I am wondering maybe if it did get execute but maybe not the same DB you are checking. that happened to me before.

Comment: The most weird thing guys is that I have already performed Selects and inserts successfully in the same server, it's just the execution for SP that it doesnt work

Comment: but if you execute the sp directly in the database it works as expected?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO Yes buddy when I go to DB and execute manually that works thats so so weird. I will create my scripts in a GitHub repository to show you guys more details about my script

Comment: ok just out of curiosity can you change your driver to the newer one for MsSQL 2008. also is your server using `local`? if not try that too . so do `pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', server = '(local)',
        database = 'xxx', uid = 'xx', pwd = 'xxx')` and run the program again. and see if this affects your DB

Comment: I was wondering maybe you don't have the correct driver. But another reason could be you didn't commit after you execute your sp. so put `conn.commit()` after `cursor.execute()`

Comment: You could try doing `conn.autocommit = True` before calling your SP to see if that helps any.

Comment: Buddy figured it out doing conn.autocommit = True. Even if I did a commit within my SP thanks buddy. How can reach you on LinkedIn or something like that. thanks @GordThompson

Comment: does adding `conn.commit()` not work for you? I would have thought that does the same trick as setting autocommit to true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks so much everyone for your comments. Finally, in a quick comment from @GordThompson I applied the changes below and that worked.

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=XXXX;'
                       'DATABASE=XX;UID=XXXX;'
                       'PWD=XXXX')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cmd_prod_executesp = """EXEC DC_SAS_EvaluationUpdate """
conn.autocommit = True
cursor.execute(cmd_prod_executesp)

conn.close()
```

Comment: you could also set auto commit to true when you create the connection. It is seen more common that way. `conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=XXXX;'
                       'DATABASE=XX;UID=XXXX;'
                       'PWD=XXXX;'
                        'autocommit=True;')` remember In pyodbc.connect() autocommit is disabled by default

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples that work for me. I'll show with parameters, because I'm guessing you'll need to know how to do that as well.

With named parameters:

```
cursor.execute('EXEC usp_get_user_data @name = ?, @username = ?', 'tim', 'flipperpa')
```

With positional parameters:

```
cursor.execute('EXEC usp_get_user_data ?, ?', None, 'flipperpa')
```

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried  even CALL and it doesnt work :( OMG. The most weird thing guys is that I have already performed Selects and inserts successfully in the same server, it's just the execution for SP that it doesnt work

Comment: IIRC, `CALL` is for MySQL. Can you try creating a really simple stored procedure that just returns something simple like `SELECT 'HELLO WORLD'` and try executing that?

Comment: buddy when I go to DB and execute manually that works thats so so weird. I will create my scripts in a GitHub repository to show you guys more details about my script

Comment: yep you want to use `exec`? since `exec` is for SQL server format `cursor.execute("exec sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')")` and `call` is for ODBC format `cursor.execute("{call sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')}") `

Comment: Are you connecting through SSMS as the same user you're connecting from Python as?

Comment: `{call ...}` (within curly brackets) is ODBC standard syntax, so it should work fine. (It does for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code looking fine as you did follow the guideline from `pyodbc`

```
//SQL Server format

cursor.execute("exec sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')")

//ODBC format

cursor.execute("{call sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')}")
```

From your comment you said you see the message

> `Process finished with exit code 0'

That means that everything worked ok.If any exception/error happened in your program your program should generate an exit code with non-zero argument.

So I think your program worked fine and the SP did get executed. However, I suspect you don't see the changes take effect in your DB could be because you didn't `commit()` your changes after you execute your sp and before you close your connection to your DB.

so add `conn.commit()` like this:

```
cursor.execute(cmd_prod_executesp)
conn.commit()
```

EDIT:
try to use the newer driver for MsSQL as well

```
 conn = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}', server = 'xxxxxx',database = 'xxxx', uid = 'xx', pwd = 'xxxx')
```